# Wrong 'Tab' Highlighted in sidebar Navigation

Tags: navigation

I have navigation for a site set up in the left hand bar.. however, whilst each page/site/whatever is highlighted when I click on it, I have an issue with Discussions.

If I click into Discussions and see the overview page, the 'Discussions' link is highlighted at the side.

However, if I then click in to a discussion, the link on the left which is highlighted is the site homepage - whilst ideally it should still be Discussions.

Example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p50w3096hel3j18/Screenshot%202013-12-16%2010.27.32.png

Any ideas as to how I can do this? Cheers.

Comment: Your dropbox link doesn't display a picture, not sure if that's just my IE settings

Comment: @Enilorac try this... https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/0/AAAqaVQYCANVz4fluXZwCKRu8Hq6tfwxK57tiHvfgPYBqA/12/57992759/png/1024x768/3/1387278000/0/2/Screenshot%202013-12-16%2010.27.32.png/3Yogdg1YYzEVTUABl5NLGFN7O-VsFDzYLXQ63qGLJ1Q

Comment: Thanks, both links work now - mioght have just been me. Unfortunately I can't answer your question but hopefully now someone else can